Manga about a party getting hunted down by monster wolves and dying before the hero appears
I'm looking for a manga that starts with an adventurer party getting hunted down by monster wolves and dying until the hero appears.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Can you remember anything else about it?  This is very sparse on detail; how did the hero save them?  How many were in the party, and how were they fighting (magic, swords, etc.)?
